# How can I extract all potential Ip address from a string?

Tags: scala, ip, extract

I want to extract all the ip addresses from a string.

Suppose I have a string
`"1.2.3.4.5.6.7"`

and I want to extract all the ip addresses from this string and it should produce the output as below :
`List("1.2.3.4","2.3.4.5","3.4.5.6","4.5.6.7")`

Things I have tried already :
Regex matching with or without positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Not regex based but given the input is as predictable as you're showing an implementation based on `sliding` could work.

`sliding(n: Int)` - groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them

```scala
List("1.2.3.4.5.6.7")
  .flatMap(_.split("\\.")) //List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
  .sliding(4) 
  .map(_.mkString(".")) 
  .toList //materialize the iterator

//List[String] = List(1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, 3.4.5.6, 4.5.6.7)
```